# How to compare values of a dictionary and make a new dictionary for the answers using python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary like:

```
dict = {'Books' : [(2,2), (3,4), (7,19)],
        'CDs'   : [(1,9), (3,5), (3,6), (10,9)],
        'Toys'  : [(0,1), (2,8), (3,3), (4,6)]}
```

I want to compare the VALUES of this dictionary and make another dict containing the similar `index[0]` in all the lists of tuples, Like:

```
dict = {'Books' : [(3,4)],
        'CDs'   : [(3,5), (3,6)],
        'Toys'  : [(3,3)]}
```

There can't be more than one similar tuples with index[0] in all values of dict!
I have found multiple answers for this problems but nothing positive happened.
The following dict is not my case:

```
dict = {'Books' : [(2,2), (3,4), (7,19)],
        'CDs'   : [(1,9), (2,7)(3,5), (3,6), (10,9)],
        'Toys'  : [(0,1), (2,8), (3,3), (4,6)]}
```

like '2' at index[0] occurs in all the values of dict!

Comment: Please define "similar" precisely.

Comment: Would the result of `Chebyshev distance` count as similar? EG: is (3,4) similar to (2,3) and (4,3)?

Comment: By "similar" maybe you mean "common"? As in: "make another dict containing the values for which `index[0]` is common to all the lists". Am I interpreting it right? (in your first example, `2` was not common - since it was absent from `'CDs'` - but in your second example it became common)

Comment: @ mgibsonbr: EXACTLY :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need a set with all the first elements (grouped by key):

```
firsts = [set([pair[0] for pair in v]) for v in dict.values()]
```

To find which value appear in all entries, you can do a set intersection:

```
similar = reduce(lambda x,y: x.intersection(y), firsts)
```

Then you can filter the dict to have only pairs that belong to the intersection:

```
filtered = { k:[pair for pair in v if pair[0] in similar] \
             for k,v in dict.items() }
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "similar" you mean the first index of the tuples is the same, then something like:

```
d =  {'Books' : [(2,2), (3,4), (7,19)],
        'CDs'   : [(1,9), (3,5), (3,6), (10,9)],
        'Toys'  : [(0,1), (2,8), (3,3), (4,6)]}

def find_when(d, n):
    return {k: [el for el in v if el[0] == n] for k, v in d.iteritems()}

print find_when(d, 3)
# {'CDs': [(3, 5), (3, 6)], 'Books': [(3, 4)], 'Toys': [(3, 3)]}
```